# css transform origin not scaling from center

Tags: css, svg

i have a svg icon with three parts, the fb logo, a ring of dashes which is currently set to not visible and an outer ring. the outer ring is the problem. i am using the hover psuedo selector to expand the ring with the scale() property. it scales fine, the problem is that it shoots off to the right instead of just staying put in the center. according to what i have read using transform-origin: center center or 50% 50% should fix it (and it has on the other logos ive been working on) it does not in this instance.

heres the pen the relevant code starts on line 24

https://codepen.io/cole-pratt/pen/poJJdzy?editors=1100

```
.facebook-outline, .facebook-detail {
  transition: 300ms all;
  transform-origin: center center;
}

.facebook-detail {
  opacity: 0;
}

.facebook-icon-group:hover {
  .facebook-outline {transform: scale(1.8); opacity: 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right the default is not to scale from the centre it's to scale the viewBox. You can fix that by adding

```
transform-box: fill-box;
```

e.g.

```
.facebook-outline, .facebook-detail {
  transition: 300ms all;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

.

Comment: thankyou, just wondering though why it works correctly for the youtube logo without that but not for the facebook logo?

Comment: The youtube logo is in the centre of the viewBox (or near enough so) and per my answer that's the box we find the centre of by default.